# How to change x-axis datetime format in QlikView

Tags: datetime-format, qlikview

First time Qlikview user here. Trying to get x-axis only showing the date from the timestamp. Here is the example,

[image: crazy long timestamp with meaningless time]

It would be lovely to be able to remove the time. Does anybody know how to do this? I tried some simple script in the Used Dimension section under Dimension tab hoping to get only the date. It didn't work. It looked like this:

```
=date(floor(timestamp#(SomeDate,'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss'))) as record_date
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to remove time than you rather use `Date#` function instead of `timestamp#`? 
Below one is the sample one:-

```
Date#( DateField, 'M/D/YY')
```